# How to handle multiple email addresses across multiple domains using Google Apps?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have `domain1.com`, `domain2.com` and `domain3.com`. `domain1` is my primary business email address setup with Google Apps as a catch-all email. I've added and verified `domain2.com` but I have to create a user, login to the account and setup forwarding to my primary address `admin@domain1.com`.

Ideally I'd like to add quite a few domain names to Google Apps and consolidate all email addresses into one inbox.

Is there a more efficient way to deal with these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You can add domain aliases: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295

Comment: If you read the question you'll see I've done that already.

Comment: I've not done exactly as you describe, but I've got several email addresses forwarding to my main Gmail account (I reply from the appropriate address). Reading the above docs from google, it appears that an alias _should_ do what you want... What's not working?